# How to initialize constructor attirbute as empty list?

Tags: python, constructor

I am creating a new class that takes three attributes: term (a str representing course term), grades (a list of tuples), and num_courses (an int representing number of courses)
grades has to be initialized as an empty list and num_courses as 0. Whenever I run my code with other methods I get an error saying 'AttributeError: type object 'GradeRecords' has no attribute 'grades'. I think my constructor is wrong, but I don't know why. Thank you in advance!

```
class GradeRecords:
    """represents a grade for a class
    Instance Attributes: term (str), grades (list of tuples),
    num_courses (int)
    """
    
    def __init__(self, term, new_tuple()):
        self.term = term
        
        #create a list from the input new_tuple
        self.grades = []
        GradeRecords.grades.append(new_tuple)
        
        self.num_courses = 0
        GradeRecords.num_courses += len(self.grades)
```

Comment: Is GradeRecords the class which owns the `__init__` method?

Comment: `new_tuple()` is not a syntactically valid parameter name. The signature of `__init__` does not match the description in the class's docstring. *How* are you creating instances of `GradeRecords`? You need a [mcve].

Comment: yes, the __init__ is supposed to be the constructor for GradeRecords

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning self.grades to '[]' but in your def **init** line you call it 'new_tuple()'. Rename it to grades or keep the same naming.

```
self.new_tuple = []
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirements correctly, I think you have a minor error in the code. It should be `self.grades.append(new_tuple)`, because in your code you try to append to the **grades property of the class** `GradeRecords`. However, this class doesn't have this property. It is created in the `__init__` meaning the created **object has this property**, but not the class.

```
def __init__(self, term, new_tuple):
    self.term = term
    
    #create a list from the input new_tuple
    self.grades = []
    self.grades.append(new_tuple)
    
    self.num_courses = 0
    GradeRecords.num_courses += len(self.grades)
```

If you want to have default values of `0` and `[]` for all objects you create from the class, you could also assign them on class level. Also, I think you don't want to add `+=` the length of grades to `num_courses`, but you want to set it `=`.

```
class GradeRecords:

    grades = []
    num_courses = 0

    def __init__(self, term, new_tuple):
        self.term = term
        
        #create a list from the input new_tuple
        self.grades.append(new_tuple)
        
        GradeRecords.num_courses += len(self.grades)
```